# fit method in Sklearn. when using KNeighborsClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn_clf =KNeighborsClassifier() 
knn_clf.fit(x_train[:92000],y_train[:92000]) #1st method call
knn_clf.fit(x_train[92000:123000],y_train[92000:123000]) #2nd method call
```

My doubt is when I call fit method like this does the 2nd call trains the model once again from scratch ? or it will add to what it has learned from the previous fit call(1st method call) ?

What I am trying to achieve is to do batch wise training as laptop can't handle the data if I use the complete dataset at once!
Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: x_train contains MNIST dataset which is also augmented .

Comment: I don't think the concept of batch training makes any sense for KNN... but maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @Julien So what can i do to fully utilize my dataset?

Comment: It does train the model from scratch indeed.

Comment: Get a better computer? Or use a method where batch training makes sense like Neural nets...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you call fit method, it tries to fit the model. If you call fit method multiple times, it will try to refit the model & as @Julien pointed out, batch training doesn't make any sense for KNN.

KNN will consider all the data points & pick up the top K nearest neighbors.So if your data is large it would take more time.

All you can do is downscale your data or increasing your system memory size.

Comment: Ohh i didnt know that ! I am new to machine learning. I think i will go with downscaling the data

Answer (score 0):

There is no training in a k-NN Classifier as the Query Point (from Test Data) is mandatory to find it's nearest neighbour and classify based on the majority vote.
If there would be no Query Point (Test Data), what the model will do by training on the Train Data?.

Perhaps, the model.fit() method for k-NN Classifier does no training but stores the dataset in an efficient Data Structure for searching.

When we try to classify a datapoint (from Test Data) using model.predict(), the k-NN will then find the 'k' nearest neighbours from the Train Data and classify the query point based on the majority vote.

Coming to your question, the second fit method will overwrite the stored data of the 'knn_clf' model and will discard the data stored by the first fit method. Let's prove this by an example:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier}

# Load the Iris Dataset
irisDS = datasets.load_iris()

# Get Features and Labels
features, labels = iris.data, iris.target

knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier() # Create a KNN Classifier Model Object

queryPoint = [[9, 1, 2, 3]] # Query Datapoint that has to be classified

# Case 1: fit on whole Dataset (total 150 datapoints)
knn_clf.fit(features, labels)
print(knn_clf.predict(queryPoint)) # Prints Class 1
# Query Point belongs to Class 1 if all the Dataset is taken in the fit method

# Case 2: fit on a subset of whole Dataset (last 40 datapoints)
knn_clf.fit(features[110:], labels[110:])
print(knn_clf.predict(queryPoint)) # Prints Class 2
# Query Point belongs to Class 2 if last 40 Datapoints are taken in the fit method => Wrong Classification because of a small subset of Training Data.

Case 3: fit on subsets of whole Dataset (last 40 and then first 110 datapoints)
knn_clf.fit(features[110:], labels[110:])
knn_clf.fit(features[:110], labels[:110])
print(knn_clf.predict(queryPoint)) # Prints Class 1
# Query Point belongs to Class 1 if 'last 40 and then first 110 datapoints' are taken in the fit method => Correct Classification because the Training Data has luckily majority of Class 1.

# Case 4: fit on subsets of whole Dataset (first 110 and then last 40 datapoints)
knn_clf.fit(features[:110], labels[:110])
knn_clf.fit(features[110:], labels[110:])
print(knn_clf.predict(queryPoint)) # Prints Class 2
# Query Point belongs to Class 2 if 'first 110 and then last 40 datapoints' are taken in the fit method => Wrong Classification because of a small subset of Training Data.
```

If we see, the Query Point belongs to Class 1 (when fit on whole dataset) but is predicted wrong in Case 4 (your case), even if we assume that we have taken whole Dataset in batches (wrong assumption).
This implies that the data in the recent/latest fit method is only considered by the KNN Classifier Model.